# Cannot add my logging in ASP.NET Core controllers with Serilog

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, serilog

I have a controller that is using ASPNET Core v2

```
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                new WebListenerCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                {
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting WebListener on {url}");

                    return new WebHostBuilder().UseHttpSys()
                        .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseApplicationInsights()
                        .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                        .UseUrls(url)
                         .UseSerilog(_log, true)
                        .Build();
                }))
        };
    }
```

As you can see above I am using the command UseSeriLog providing a log instance that has already been injected

```
    public ServiceFabric(StatelessServiceContext context, ServiceLoggerFactory serviceLoggerFactory, ServiceConfiguration configuration)
        : base(context)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => context);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => serviceLoggerFactory);
        Argument.IsNotNull(() => configuration);

        _configuration = configuration;

        _log = serviceLoggerFactory.EnrichLoggerForStatelessServiceContext(this);
        _log.Information($"Service constructed {GetType().Name}");
    }
```

This works really well as I do get a lot of logging

However, when I try to put my own logging in using standard

```
Log.Information("MESSAGE");
```

This does not get through

Does anyone know what could cause this?

I use AutoFac which has a logger registered in my container

```
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var appName = assembly.GetName().Name;
            var appVersion = assembly.InformationalVersion();

            var logger = ApplicationLoggingHelper.ConfigureLogging(appName, appVersion);
            builder.Register(container => logger)
                .SingleInstance();

            ApplicationContainer = builder.Build();
```

There is a hack I can apply which simply creates a property in my base controller as a new log but thats not ideal and I would prefer to know what could be causing this issue

Paul

Comment: If you use `Log.Information` that goes through the static instance of the logger. Did you ever set the static instance? `Log.Logger = logger` or something like that?

Comment: Thanks that worked when I added it to my base controller.  I was hoping to use the instance I already created in my autofac container as shown above but at least this works.  I guess this isnt too much of an overhead.  I now create a new log instance and set Log.Logger to that in the constructor of my controller

Comment: If you do that, you change the static logger *everywhere*. That doesn't sound like a good idea. Better to pass the logger instance around rather than screwing up the main static logger you use for your "normal" logging.

Comment: Ok I will have to do that cos nothing else works